# Why a vue.js method don't change a variable setting false to true, is very simple but doesn't works

Tags: vue.js

I have this div, mostrarInfo is setted to false by default, this works, the div is not created:

```
<div id="infoMnjEnviado"> 
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" v-if="mostrarInfo"> 
        <strong>Mensaje enviado!</strong> 
        <br>        

        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

And i have this button to show foward div:
`<a class="btn btn-success" id="envForm" v-on:click="mostrarInfoMensaje">Enviar</a>`

And this vue script logic:

```
<script>
        const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                mostrarInfo: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            mostrarInfoMensaje() {
                this.mostrarInfo = true
            }
        }
    })
    app.mount('#infoMnjEnviado')

</script>
```

Why the variable `mostrarInfo` is never set to true?

And why the element `div id="infoMnjEnviado"` is created and destroyed creating a non good effect, how i can prevent this? with a d-none only?

I triyed some thinks but this is very simple. No many possibities to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the method "mostrarInfoMensaje" outside the "infoMnjEnviado" div? Vue can only work inside this div.